Strong convergence in $L^1 \implies$ weak convergence in $H^{-1}$?

Let $U$ be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Prove or disprove:
Strong convergence in $L^1(U) \implies$ weak convergence in $H^{-1}(U).$

Attempt: Suppose $f_n \to f$ in $L^1(U)$ strongly. As the space is reflexive, we need to show for $g \in H_0^1(U)$,  $$\big<f_n,g\big> \to \big<f,g\big> $$
where $\big<.,.\big> $ is the pairing between $H^{-1}(U)$ and $H_0^1(U)$.
Since $ L^1(U) \subset L^2 (U) \subset H^{-1}(U)$ and $L^{\infty}(U)\cap H_0^1(U)$ is dense in $H_0^1(U)$, if the pairing is given by $$\big<u,v\big>=\int_U uv$$ then $$\Big|\big<f_n-f,g\big>\Big|\leq ||f_n-f||_{L^1}||g||_{L^{\infty}} \to 0$$
Is there a way to extend this for any arbitrary pairing or is this result false in general?

The result is wrong. The reason is that $H^1_0(U)$ is not continuously embedded into $L^\infty(U)$ if $U \subset \mathbb R^d$ with $d\ge 2$.

The idea for the counterexample is to use the standard sequence in $L^1$ that converges to the Dirac functional: the sequence of functions $f_n:=\frac1{s^3} \chi_{B_s(0)}$ is bounded in $L^1$, and $ \langle f_n,g\rangle \to c_2\cdot g(0)$ for continuous $g$ with $c_2 := \frac43\pi$. Now $H^1$ functions are not continuous, so this convergence not work for $H^1$ functions.
In the counterexample, the functions $f_n$ are scaled so that they converge to zero in $L^1$.

So here is the counterexample:
Let $U = B_1(0)\subset \mathbb R^3$ and define $g:= |x|_2^{-1/4}-1$.
Then $g\in H^1_0(U)$ but $g\not\in L^\infty(U)$.
For $s\in (0,1)$ define the function
$$
f_s(x) := \frac{s^{1/8}}{s^3} \chi_{B_s(0)}(x).
$$
Then $\|f_s\|_{L^1} = c_2s^{1/8} \to 0$ for $s\searrow 0$.
And
$$
\langle f_s,g\rangle = \frac{s^{1/8}}{s^3} \int_{B_s(0)} g(x)dx - \|f_s\|_{L^1},
$$
where
$$
\frac{s^{1/8}}{s^3} \int_{B_s(0)} g(x)dx
 = \frac{s^{1/8}}{s^3}  \int_0^s r^{-1/4}r^2dr \\
=\frac{s^{1/8}}{s^3}  \cdot \frac {11}4 s^{11/4}
= \frac {11}4 s^{-1/8} \to +\infty
$$
for $s\searrow0$. This shows $\langle f_s,g\rangle \to +\infty$
for $s\searrow0$.
And the sequence $(f_{1/n})$ is unbounded in $H^{-1}$.

Thanks for the counterexample. But isn't $g=1$ on $\partial U$? How is $g$ in $H_0^1(U)$ then? Also, would this result be true if we replace $L^{\infty}$ with $L^p$ for some $1 \leq p < \infty ?$

Corrected $g$ to satisfy the boundary conditions, which does not change the conclusion.
